# Javascript Switch Statement for Adobe Acrobat Form

Tags: javascript, forms, acrobat

I have an Adobe Acrobat form with the fields "Store Address" and "Store Phone". The Store Address field is a dropdown with the address as the option and the store number (e.g. "Store 1") as the export value. The Store Phone field has a custom calculation script on it with the following code:

```js
var store = this.getField("Store Address");

switch(store) {
case 'Store 1':
   event.value = '867-5309';
   break;
case 'Store 2':
   event.value = '555-1234';
   break;
default:
   event.value = '';
   break;
}
```

Presently, selecting an address from the pulldown menu does nothing. What did I do wrong?

Comment: There's not enough code here to know, where are attaching the event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first line, you're only getting the Field object, not it's value. Use...

```
var store = this.getField("Store Address").value;
```